# Ubuntu or Debian package for creating book covers?

Tags: software-recommendation, graphics

I need to create a book cover, and would like to know what are the possible ways to do that using Ubuntu or Debian packages -- but I'm not an expert in graphic design. So far I know of:

- LaTeX: it would possibly take too long to get all details right (choosing the right fonts, positioning elements, etc)
- Scribus: seems to not make common tasks easy (I couldn't easily find a way to centralize text in a frame, or a frame in a page for example)
- Gimp: a bit too complex maybe.

Are there any other packages that would make the task easier?

*edit:* it's my own book (self-publishing -- it's not for a publishing company). I'll probably want one or two images, the title and one or two lines of text.

Answer (score 5):

Well that heavily depends on your needs. The packages/ways that you mentioned are not overly complex given the tasks that they can solve.

You should probably give more details on: 
What do you want on the book cover, and who needs that cover? 
E.g. If you have a publishing company, then they might want a certain format.

To give some basic recommendations:
Assuming you want text, then why not use LibreOffice Writer (or KOffice or Abiword)? 
Assuming you want graphics, then Inkscape (or LibreOffice Draw) might be another option.

Comment: +1 for the Inkscape recommendation, though it's not too simple to use at first.

Comment: A friend of mine just published a children's book, and did all the artwork with Inkscape and Gimp.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing particularly difficult about handling alignment of objects on a page or text inside text frame.

For the former use *Align and Distribute* palette (available from *Windows* menu), for the latter look inside *Properties Palette* (F2) on the *Text* tab (or use text styles , F3) from ground up.

If you are a designer, you are supposed to grok professional software :)